# Why does my 404 page (Next.jss SSG) work differently on localhost than production (AWS Amplify)?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, aws-amplify

**pages/404.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Error from "next/error";

export default function NotFound() {
return <Error statusCode={404} />;
}
```

**AWS Amplify Dashboard >> Rewrites and redirects:**

Next.js's Amplify tutorial recommends using index.html below, but I got the 404 page to show up on production based on a Stackoverflow answer ([Problems setting up 404 page on Gatsby site in AWS Amplify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56634467/problems-setting-up-404-page-on-gatsby-site-in-aws-amplify)).

```
Source address: /<*>
Target address: /404.html
Type: 404 (Rewrite)
```

**Issue:**

I am redirected to my website.com/404 if I visit https://mywebsite.com/this_page_does_not_exist. We want to monitor our 404 pages during a site migration and this is causing our analytics program to show the url for all 404 visits is https://mywebsite.com/404.

**Hack Solution:**

Send a manual request to our analytics program with the name of the page useEffects.